# How to remove the "default button" border?

Tags: c++, c, gtk

When you have a `GtkButton` in GTK and it is the **default** for some window (will be activated when you press Enter), a tiny border is draw around it to inform the user that the button is the default button. How to remove this border ?

I already tried: `default-border` and `default-outside-border` style properties.

Comment: Why do you want to, should an application try to be consistent with the rest of the OS?

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't apply to my app.

Comment: @JoeD No, an application shouldn't try to be consistent with the rest of the operating system.  I want programs, not created by the OS maker, to not look like everything else.  When a program has a personality, and you see that personality across multiple platforms, it feels like home.  Might just be a personal preference, tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours finding for this, I've discovered it:

```
 gtk_button_set_relief(GTK_BUTTON(button_widget), GTK_RELIEF_HALF);
```

GTK should have a gallery showing how this changes the button behavior.

Comment: In fairness, GTK is missing a lot of what should be available.  Documentation is just as important as the programming, but nobody told them.